# XML document containing &isin; not valid - how to output using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML document, and one of the nodes contains `&isin;` like this:

```
<Text>&isin;</Text>
```

It tells me that it is invalid XML, so I tried this:

```
<Text><![CDATA[&isin;]]></Text>
```

The XML is now valid, but when I output the content of the node in my XSLT transform using  `<xsl:value-of select="."/>`, it outputs the following:  `&amp;isin;`.

I want it to output simply `&isin;` as it is a transformation to HTML and I want the ∈ symbol to show up! Am I missing any tricks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just disable output escaping like this

```
<xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes">...
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, Stack Overflow is super helpful! I just saw this advert:

[image: advert]

... and I thought "ohhhh XML entity reference". Looked it up and putting `&#8712;` into my XML works great!